# Using logarithmic and linear axis scale together

Tags: qt, axis-labels, logarithm, qwt

I am using qwt 6.1.0. I tried:

`linEngine = new QwtLinearScaleEngine;

  logEngine = new QwtLogScaleEngine;`

these codes to make my axis logarithmic and linear. But I want to use them together for example;

1    - 10      ---> in this interval must be  linear

10   - 10000   ---> in this interval must be logarithmic

[image]

is that possible?

Comment: If I were your user, I'd hate you - for such "innovations" are almost always misguided and go against what is commonly expected. You need to *at least* provide a visual indication (a broken line symbol) on **both** the axis *and* the plot, at the location where the change of scaling occurs. What is the purpose of this craziness?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not out of the box. You will have to create your own implementation of `QwtScaleEngine`. Use the methods of the API to split the incoming arguments in linear and exponential parts and then you can delegate to private instances of both classes to actually do the work.

But that will only give you the scale. You'll have to do the same for rendering the actual data.